# Is there somebody who is getting build failure while deploying to azure devops as below

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, csproj

I am trying to deploy my function app on azure using the following code:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <WarningsAsErrors></WarningsAsErrors>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>**</DefaultItemExcludes>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="1.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

But it's giving error as below:

```
/home/vsts/.nuget/packages/microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator/1.0.2/build/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.targets(20,5): warning : To install missing framework, download: [/home/vsts/work/1/s/extensions.csproj]
/home/vsts/.nuget/packages/microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator/1.0.2/build/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.targets(20,5): warning : https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=2.0.0&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.20.04-x64 [/home/vsts/work/1/s/extensions.csproj]
/home/vsts/.nuget/packages/microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator/1.0.2/build/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.targets(20,5): error : Metadata generation failed. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/extensions.csproj]

Build FAILED.

/home/vsts/.nuget/packages/microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator/1.0.2/build/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.targets(20,5): warning : You must install or update .NET to run this application. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/extensions.csproj]
/home/vsts/.nuget/packages/microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator/1.0.2/build/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.targets(20,5): warning :  [/home/vsts/work/1/s/extensions.csproj]
/home/vsts/.nuget/packages/microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator/1.0.2/build/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.targets(20,5): warning : App: /home/vsts/.nuget/packages/microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator/1.0.2/tools/netstandard2.0/generator/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.Console.dll [/home/vsts/work/1/s/extensions.csproj]
```

Awaiting for Some Responses.

Comment: You have to tell us the environment where you are building your app. The mentioned resources could be missing.

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket?

Answer (score 0):

From your Project Configuration file and error log, it shows that you are using .net2.0 and deploying the project on Azure DevOps Microsoft-hosted agent.

Refer to this doc about [ubuntu.20.04 Microsoft-Hosted agent](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-Readme.md).

.net2.0 is not pre-installed in the agent. It can cause the issue.

You can try to add the task: [Use .NET Core task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops) in your Pipeline and Run the Pipeline again.

For example:

```
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 2.0.x'
  inputs:
    version: 2.0.x
 xxxxx
```